# Como alterar um atributo no banco através de um botão

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, active-record

Estou criando um pequeno projeto da faculdade, em `Ruby on Rails` e me deparei com um problema: tenho uma tabela chamada `Person` e outra chamada `Tools`. As pessoas possuem muitas ferramentas e cada ferramenta e possuída por uma pessoa.

Preciso adicionar um recurso que possibilite o empréstimo de ferramentas entre as pessoas do sistema. Para isso, criei um atributo chamado '`loan`' na tabela `Tools`, que se tiver o valor `0` significa que a ferramenta não esta emprestada e se for `1`, que esta emprestada. Na view show das ferramentas, criei um botão com a função de pedir emprestado a ferramenta.

Meu problema esta em como fazer para que esse botão altere o atribulo '`loan`' da tabela `Tools` de `0` para `1` e vice versa? Alguém teria uma solução melhor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer uma action em `ToolsController`, onde passará o id da ferramenta, nesse controller você realiza a ação de emprestar.

Sugiro que você ao invés de colocar um atributo `loan`, coloque o `user_id` do usuário que está realizado o empréstimo, assim você poderá controlar melhor esse relacionamento. Ou seja:

- `user_id` com `id` == ferramenta emprestada para `user`
- `user_id` sem `id` == ferramenta *livre* para empréstimo

Na action bastaria você associar o `current_user` à `tool` referente.